# Render ChoiceField options in Django template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Given a `ChoiceField` in Django

```
fruits = ChoiceField(label="Fruits", choices=(('A', 'Apple'),
    ('B', 'Banana'), ('C', 'Cherry')
)
```

How do I display the form options in Django Templates in 1.9? For example, I tried the following but cannot display the form data:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
      <tr>
      <th>
        <label for="{{form.fruits.id_label}}">  
          {{form.fruits.label}}
        </label>
      </th>
      <td>{% for value, displayable in form.fruits.choices %}
            <option value="{{value}}">{{displayable}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
      </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: this link i give explain all you wan to know about custom render choiceField ! good luck !

Comment: @rakwen i read the documentation but still to no avail. Maybe you could help with this instead?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default, Django provides us with a simple drop-down list as a visual representation of the choice field. Just create and an instance of the form in your view, pass it in the context. Here is an example,

let's say our example model is,

```
gender = (
    ('x', 'Male'),
    ('y', 'Female'),
    )

class User(models.Model):
      gender = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, default='',choices=gender,verbose_name="gender")
```

and our model form,

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kargs)

    class Meta:
         model = User
         fields = '__all__'
```

Just create an instance of the form in your view, pass it in the context:

```
def my_view(request):
    form = UserForm()
    return render_response('template.html',{'form': form})
```

and then display it in the template using {{ form.my_choice_field }}.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Gender</label>
    <select name="gender" class="selectpicker" data-title="Select Gender" data-style="btn-default btn-block" data-menu-style="dropdown-blue">
    {% for x,y in form.fields.gender.choices %}
       <option value="{{ x }}"{% if form.fields.gender.value == x %} selected{% endif %}>{{ y }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: How would you add a null option for the option to go unspecified.