# Django dropdown is not populated

Tags: python, django, dropdown

I want my dropdown to get populated with values from one of my db tables in my Django project, yet it remains blank and I can't figure out why.

This is my html code of my home.html page:

```
<select name="regions" id="regions">
    {% for item in regions_list %}
    <option val="{{ item.name_reg }}"> {{ item.name_reg }} </option>    
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

models.py:

```
class data_reg(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name_reg = models.TextField(db_column='NAME_REG', blank=True, null=True) 

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'reg'
```

views.py:

```
def MyView(request):
    regions_list = RegionChoiceField()

    query_results_dict = {
        'regions_list': regions_list,
    }

    return render(request,'home.html', query_results_dict)
```

forms.py:

```
class RegionChoiceField(forms.Form):

    regions = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=data_immo.objects.values_list("name_reg", flat=True).distinct(),
        empty_label=None
    )
```

Comment: Why have you created a RegionChoiceField class inherited from forms.Form?

Comment: I initially took the code from someone else and just modified it. It was already like that (except that Region was called something else). I'm new to Django, so there are still many concepts that I don't understand very much at the moment.

Comment: OK, so RegionChoiceField is just badly named and should perhaps be called RegionChoiceForm (because it's actually a form, while regions is actually a field within the form). And what's being called query_results_dict is actually a context. It might be worth doing a review of the naming conventions in this code because they may ultimately confuse your attempts to reconcile the code with the Django documentation and impact your ability to understand it.

Comment: And see if this example helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36724255/render-choicefield-options-in-django-template

Comment: Even though I felt a bit confused by this solution, I've tried it, but as a result I only got an empty dropdown. This is what I ended up with in my template and am really not sure if it is correct: 
<select name="regions" id="regions">
    {% for items in form.name_reg %}
       <option value="{{ items.name_reg }}">{{ items.name_reg }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work and did it by avoiding using forms.py. I simply generated my 'regions_list' variable directly in views.py and only after that it managed to get properly recognized. So this is how it finally looked like:

```
def MyView(request):
    regions_list = data_immo.objects.values_list("name_reg", flat=True).distinct()

    query_results_dict = {
        'regions_list': regions_list,
    }

    return render(request,'home.html', query_results_dict)
```

Also, I amended my html code slightly, as per Ken's suggestion:

```
<select name="regions" id="regions">
    {% for item in regions_list %}
    <option val="{{ item.name_reg }}"> {{ item}} </option>    
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

when passing ModelChoiceField to context I think the template should be different.

```
{% for item in regions_list %}
<option val="{{ item.name_reg }}"> {{ item.name_reg }} </option>    
{% endfor %}
```

change to

```
{% for item in regions_list %}
{{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

or even simpler, just put your form in the template

```
{{regions_list}}
```

Hope this works,

Greeting 
Ken

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. When trying the second option, I simply have "Regions:" as choice in the dropdown. The first option only returned an empty dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and it seems to work for me.
Can you print the query in your forms.py

```
print(data_immo.objects.values_list("name_reg", flat=True).distinct())
```

This will show the query set in your terminal:

```
<QuerySet ['a_value']>
```

I find it always good to print at various levels for debugging, fast and easy.